# How can I debug my own malloc in assembly using gdb on a real program like ls?

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, shared-libraries

I am trying to recode the malloc functions (and free, calloc, realloc) in x86_64 assembly for fun. I have a good amount of code and it works when I'm using these functions as a "my_malloc" function in my own C files to test them. But now I'm trying to use it with ls to get a real example. I get a Segmentation Fault and I don't really know where to start debugging.

I compile all these asm functions in a `libmy_malloc.so` and here is what happens when I use it with `ls` (basically it's a SEGV):

```bash
> LD_PRELOAD=./libmy_malloc.so ls
fish: Job 1, 'LD_PRELOAD=./libmy_malloc.so /u…' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

I don't know how to start debugging because in my own tests everything seems fine but with `ls` I believe the SEGV happens before the main function because I used `gdb` to try to understang what was going on and I got this:

```bash
> gdb ls
gdb$ break malloc
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4690
gdb$ set environment LD_PRELOAD=./libmy_malloc.so
gdb$ r
During startup program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

I added code to my `malloc` and `free` function that print something to see how they were used before the main and `malloc` is called at least once. I'm probably messing with the memory or there are regulations concerning `malloc` that I'm not aware of but now I don't know what to do or where to start or what to do to debug or to find more informations.

Also to be clear, when I'm using these functions in my own tests I call them `my_malloc`, `my_free` etc. but when I'm using them with `ls` I renamed them with the right name.

Comment: Maybe syslog has crash info or you can get a core dump.

Comment: If you use `starti`, execution will stop before the very first instruction of user-space for the process (after execve).  So the program counter will point into the dynamic linker.  Hopefully if you `cont` from there, GDB will catch the SIGSEGV.  But I haven't tried this.

Comment: Perhaps start with debugging it in this mode (with proper names and LD_PRELOAD) with your own simple test.

Comment: when I use the functions with their real names and I do `LD_PRELOAD=./libmy_malloc.so ./my_prog` it works fine, I have no errors, that's why I tried the next step: using it with a real program. Also I tried `starti` instead of `run` in gdb and still the same error message saying there is a SEGV during startup program

Comment: Try `set startup-with-shell off` then `starti`.  By default GDB invokes a shell, which then invokes your application.  I suspect your malloc replacement is causing the shell to crash.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew it worked and I'm able to see what's happening before the main. I trialed and errored and deduced that I needed to push some registers on the stack at the beginning of my version of malloc and pop them at the end. Thanks to that, `ls` works quite a bit more but still crashes, I'm trying to find out why. Also I don't understand why I have to do that kind of tricks with the registers but it works

Comment: Consult calling convention if you have not yet done so. That specifies what registers need to be preserved, how arguments are passed, stack alignment and such.